# Render a chart for incidences based on Age

Tags: kql

i'm rather noob at data analysis so... this might be extremely simple, just my logic is missing...

I have a table with several rows but only 2 matter: CreateDate & IncidentId

Basically i'm trying to render a piechart that would section things like: x incidents >30d; y incidents >15 and <30; z incidents >7 and <15; aa incidents <7

--

I'm starting out from a query from a former colleague who created a baseline to show this all in table form, initially I was trying to round down the CreateDate value to just DD-MM-YYYY, but i'm starting to struggle...

I managed to narrow down the CreateDate with bin() ... was thinking to use TrimEnd() to narrow down the dates... but i think i'm overcomplicating it....... I'm currently stuck at:

| project bin(CreateDate,1d), IncidentId

[Current Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKUi8.png)

If anyone has a couple of tips I'd be extremely appreciated!... i'm sure it's something simple that i'm missing...
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, only the *CreateDate* column matters

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let Incidents = materialize(range i from 1 to 100 step 1 | extend CreateDate  = ago(50d * rand()));
// Solution starts here.
Incidents
| summarize count() by period = case
                                (
                                    now() - CreateDate >= 30d, "30d <= x"
                                   ,now() - CreateDate >= 15d, "15d <= x < 30d"
                                   ,now() - CreateDate >=  7d,  "7d <= x < 15d"
                                   ,"x < 7d"
                                )
| render piechart
```

| period | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| 30d <= x | 37 |
| x < 7d | 12 |
| 7d <= x < 15d | 25 |
| 15d <= x < 30d | 26 |

[image: Pie Chart]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA6WRwWrDMBBE7/6KwSe7pLFNCT4k7qW99NJLv2BrbWyBLRlpTdOSj+86lNBDIYYuaEFo582gLQq80TgNDENC6NhxILHebfHqBRMFgT9Cekb0w3x5SQYWvLjWGnYS0WAk4WBpsF+cBXIdw+IY/IgK4lGVJaLwpLcz+CTsDJ4Cq+ZZD1RPnc92pcEdVG2yPM/3SaHBfgxVrTEieg68Ta7GyRlxHkcKaovWz06yHO+fmDSLN4ptKXKCG5XdnFjK+Q+F3//O/djgoTQbpNpxaHBK15A2f5Oq3ULSfiHhsKD/w0OtPKT1lafodbx0ma5XDOf6/0F3yQGT5bbXFX0DV/o0QU0CAAA=)